# Python - Check If Multiple String Entries Contain Invalid Chars

Tags: python

Using Python v2.x, I have 3 variables that I want to ask the user for, as below:

```
def Main():
    Class_A_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: '))
    Class_B_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class B tickets sold: '))
    Class_C_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class C tickets sold: '))
```

How can I check if the user input is a valid input. IE: I want only numerical data entered. I have done this once before using 'chars = set('0123456789') and the 'WHILE' functions, but cannot seem to get it to work for multiple inputs.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand : 'int()' already checks if an input is an integer (you get an exception otherwise). I mean, you can just put all this in a try…catch block ?

Comment: Why have you asked both this and the nearly-identical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439786/python-check-if-multiple-string-entries-contain-invalid-chars ? The latter is probably (rightly) going to get closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `int` on something that isn't a valid integer will raise a `ValueError` exception. You can just catch that. Or is there some further restriction you want that goes beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
try:
    Class_A_Input = int(raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: '))
except ValueError:
    print "First input was not a number."
    sys.exit(1)
```

Will this pattern work for your use case?

Comment: This seems to work ok, but when I type an incorrect value it types this : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Asg1BQ1.py", line 31, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:/Python27/Asg1BQ1.py", line 13, in Main
    sys.exit()
SystemExit

Answer (score 0):

Or you can omit the use of int(), and check the `Class_A_input` using `isdigit()`

```
>>> "asdf1".isdigit()
False
>>> "123".isdigit()
True
```