# Python - Check If Multiple String Entries Contain Invalid Chars

Tags: python

Using Python v2.x, I have 3 variables that I want to ask the user for, as below:

```
 def Main():

    chars = set('0123456789')

    while True:
       Class_A_Input = raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: ')
       Class_B_Input = raw_input('Enter Class B tickets sold: ')
       Class_C_Input = raw_input('Enter Class C tickets sold: ')

        if any((c in chars) for c in Class_A_Input):
            break
        else:
            print 'Wrong'

    total_profit((int(Class_A_Input)), (int(Class_B_Input)), (int(Class_C_Input)))
```

How can I check if the user input is a valid input. IE: I want only numerical data entered. I have done this once before using 'chars = set('0123456789') and the 'WHILE' functions, but cannot seem to get it to work for multiple inputs.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I have put the code in now as I have it. I moved the 'int' to the 'total_profit' variable. How can I check all inputs?

Comment: Why have you asked both this question and the nearly-identical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439731/python-check-if-multiple-string-entries-contain-invalid-chars ?

Comment: Flagging as duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getInt(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def total_profit(a, b, c):
    return 35.0*a + 25.0*b + 10.0*c

def main():
    class_a = getInt('Enter Class A tickets sold: ')
    class_b = getInt('Enter Class B tickets sold: ')
    class_c = getInt('Enter Class C tickets sold: ')

    print("Total profit is ${0:0.2f}.".format(total_profit(class_a, class_b, class_c)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has tons of nifty functions. Here is one which I think shall help you:

```
> 'FooBar'.isdigit()
> False

> '195824'.isdigit()
> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `int` on something that isn't a valid integer will raise a `ValueError` exception. You can just catch that -- either each time you call `int`, if you want to identify which input was invalid, or with a single `try` around all three.

Or is there some further restriction you want that goes beyond that?